# Robotium and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, classnotfoundexception, robotium, android-testing

Hello I have created a test project in eclipse and set things up correctly with robotium. I am testing an APK that has been signed with the debug keystore. I know this test project works from the most basic stand point because I can launch activities just find when I change the line:

```
private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.*********.*******Activity";
```

(I have starred out the real project name)

The issue I am having is that any time a test makes it to a list view that uses actionbarsherlock the test crashes.

E/AndroidRuntime(585): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity

This is the report in Logcat at the start of the red text wall created from the crash. I have this issue even if my tests consist of only sleep operations and I launch the listActivity just fine.

If you have any advice or need some other information all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the ActionBarSherlock apklib as a dependency in your test project. If you use Maven this dependency must be in scope provided.

Comment: Just to clarify: Does your comment mean that you are building with Maven?

Comment: No sorry its been a long day today. I am not using Maven. Also SherlockFragmentActivity working correctly if I remove robotium which is what I found curious. I will comment back when I figure out everything I put this on the back burning right now but thanks for your concern :D

Comment: I have a project using ActionBarSherlock that also has a test project using Robotium. IIRC both are running fine on my phone. So I'll have look whats inside.